# Error on android UI

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

I'm Learner and designing an interface but there is little problem can some one help me out, attaching screen shot original and my design and also code. 
I'm unable to adjust the button position in layout, and also if some one have links or stuff related beginners then also share
thanks.

[image: My Design]

Here is my XML code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_home__screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.sofagold.mrdeveloper.sofagold.Home_Screen"
        android:background="@android:color/black">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.8">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/home_header"
                android:layout_weight="1.3">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="62dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:background="@drawable/home_home"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:padding="5dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/home_small_logo"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="5000" />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="59dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/button8"
                    android:background="@drawable/home_back"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:padding="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.2">
                <Button
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button24"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button25"
                    android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button22"
                    android:layout_wieght="5"
                    android:background="@drawable/home_btn_bg" />
                <Button
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button22"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button24"
                    android:button_size="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/home_btn_bg" />
                <Button
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button24"
                    android:id="@+id/button25"
                    android:button_size="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/home_btn_bg" />
           RelativeLayout(end of)

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: set `</ RelativeLayout>` instead of `RelativeLayout(end of)`

Comment: You miss understood linearLayout weight in your code. Let me tell you. take a parent linear layout, and give a "weightSum" as 10, then if you add two linear layouts with "weight = 5" inside the Parent linear layout, then the two child layouts will take two halfs of the parent layout. got it..?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i just write it as decreasing the code that's why i write it in here

Comment: @sandeep i got it but i can't adjust the size of buttons in inner layout

Comment: If you share the exact design what you want  it would be easy to analyse and help

Comment: @HsRaja hey bro i did it by linear layout,,, if i get again problem then i will be back, btw thanks